# Jump in vim on same line

Tags: unix, vim

I have log files of format

```
'date' 'filename' 'something 'return status'
```

Often status goes beyond my screen.
While I am reading 'something' I press End to see status and Home to see filename.
But how do come back to exact location on that same line?
I need something like double backticks, but which returns to last position even if that is on same line.

EDIT:

1. set wrap makes log difficult to follow.
2. using marks for every other line is too much work.
   I know this is nit-pick and I am being very lazy here.

Something which can be done in 2 keys will be great. marks use 4 keys total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can `:set wrap` and see the entire line, soft-wrapped.

Second, marks will do that just fine, also within a line. Just be sure to use the `` `{mark} `` command instead of `'{mark}`, e.g. `ma` followed by `` `a ``

Finally, there are several `z...` commands for scrolling horizontally; i.e. they don't even move the cursor, but might still allow you to see the missing text. They are explained under `:help scroll-horizontal`.

Comment: set wrap makes individual logs difficult to follow, since I have to specifically look for line starting with date.

Comment: z commands seem good enough. I will upvote once I have 15 points .:)

Comment: Thanks! Also, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
nnoremap <left>  ?'\S.\{-}'<CR>
nnoremap <right> /'\S.\{-}'<CR>
```

Those mappings allow you to jump very easily from item to item.

`x` marks your current position:

```
'date' 'filename' 'something' 'return status'
←      ←          ←           x
←      ←          x           →
←      x          →           →
x      →          →           →
```

One of the good things with Vim is that it gives you all sorts of generic, low level building blocks that are relatively easy to assemble into specific, high level tools.